# Save multiple variable from an array

Tags: python

I am trying to get the three values i've retrieved from a DB into three different variables.

Here is what i did:

```
for db_values in c.fetchall():
    a = ''.join(str(db_values))
    print a

    a1 = (a[0:18])   (want to manipulate the sequence eventually)
    a2 = (a[9])

    print a1
    print a2

    >>> 3459341
    >>> 3459342
    >>> 3448743

    >>> 3459341

[error] IndexError ( index out of range: 8 )
```

So I understand why it is out of range as one line only contains 7 characters.
Using the fetchone and manipulate the record works just fine.

Could somebody let me know what the best approach is to save the second value retrieved from the db into a variable so I can manipulate it?

Comment: Why are you joining everything in a string if you want to 'manipulate it'? Just use `db_values[0]`, `db_values[1]`, `db_values[2]`, etc...

Comment: @Joris, the problem is that I want to manipulate each value that listed in the array. Using the fetchone method and then manupulate the data works just fine. But once I use the fetchall method or fetchmany, it will print all the values like (u'1660063F20160218',) , (u'1660063F20160219',) , (u'1660063F20160220',) and  then unable to manipulate it as it complains about "index out of range:22 There for I'd like to somehow concatenate the array or maybe create just one string or maybe I should even print it per row. Don't know what the best approach is.

Comment: Not sure how I could amend my code in the initial question, as I cannot paste it here. It will be unformatted and too many characters for this window. (sorry using this forum the first time, maybe I should have done a walkthrough first :-)